# An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, smtpclient

I had the following for emailing, which worked:

```
    private SmtpClient _client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@gmail.com", "password"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    public void DoThis(){
    _client.Send("from@gmail.com", to.Email, "Subject", "Body");}
    public void DoThat(){
    _client.Send("from@gmail.com", to.Email, "Subject", "Body");}
```

But it was blocking the web application until the email was sent, so I decided to try sending Asynchronously:

```
   public void DoThis(){
    var message = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", to.Email, "Subject", "Body");
   _client.SendAsync(message, null);
   }
```

Which I can see getting treated asynchronously if I debug, but I always get the following:

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous
>   operation was still pending.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Asynchrony does nothing to change the fact that long running processes should not be handled inside IIS. You should throw this into a tasks table and let a recurring scheduled task or a windows service pick it up.

Comment: @RobVious I am facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Bitsian yeah, see my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up reworking the way my Async email is sent with the following:

```
public void SendAsyncEmail(MailMessage message)
        {

            var client = new SmtpClient("mail.hover.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@site.com", "Covert00!"),
                EnableSsl = false
            };
            client.SendCompleted += (sender, error) =>
            {
                if (error.Error != null)
                {
                    // TODO: get this working
                    throw new WarningException("Email Failed to send.");
                }
                client.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();
            };
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => client.SendAsync(message, Tuple.Create(client, message)));
        }
```

Note that this is a temporary solution, and that the correct way (it seems) to handle emailing is to use some kind of [queue service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/) paired with a worker role or other windows service to pop the messages.

Comment: Check this out - the correct way to do it: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-send-email-Asynchronously-in-ASPNet-using-Background-Thread.aspx

Comment: When I try this approach, I get this error: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient'.